# Are there any GUI for appium on ubuntu

Tags: appium

I tried to install appium a week ago. After installation, execute "appium" command on terminal, and get the message as below:

> taynguyen@taynguyen:~$ node --version v5.8.0
>
> taynguyen@taynguyen:~$ npm --version 3.7.3
>
> taynguyen@taynguyen:~$ appium --version 1.5.0
>
> taynguyen@taynguyen:~$ appium [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.5.0
>
> [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

Is the setup done? Do we have appium GUI for Ubuntu like window and mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your appium server is up and running and no, there is no GUI for ubuntu.